# convert nlohmann::basic_json<> to std::tuple c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to call a function with parameters extracted from a JSON file using the nlohmann/json library.

I need to convert the JSON array retrieved from the JSON file to a tuple to call the function with.

The problem is that there's no build-up solution to convert nlohmann::basic_json<> to std::tuple in c++

the source code with comments to explain much more the programming issue :

```
using namespace std;
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "json.hpp"
#include <typeinfo>

// for convenience
using json = nlohmann::json;

void f(int a, int b, int c)
{
    std::cout << a << ":" << b << ":" << c << std::endl;
}

template <typename Function, typename Tuple, size_t... I>
auto call(Function f, Tuple t, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return f(std::get<I>(t)...);
}

template <typename Function, typename Tuple>
auto call(Function f, Tuple t)
{
    static constexpr auto size = std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value;
    return call(f, t, std::make_index_sequence<size>{});
}

int main()
{
    auto tup = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3);
    call(f, tup); //wroks fine


    std::ifstream i("tests.json");
    json j;
    i >> j;
    for (auto &element : j)
    {
        call(f, element["args"]); //issue
        //element["args"] is [1,2,3] of type nlohmann::basic_json<>
        //res = need to convert element["args"]  to tuple
        //call function like that : call(f,res)
        std::cout << element["args"] << '\n';
    }
}
```

the json file content:

```
[
  {
    "args": [1, 2, 3],
    "expected": 6
  }
]
```

Comment: Hard to achieve, the json field you read can have values of any type, `int`, `double`, more arrays or objects inside it. You would need a a `std::tuple` of `std::variant` of whatever elements you expect in your json to appear, and then parse it yourself, also your `call` function can be replaced with `std::apply`.

Comment: what should I change in code ?

Comment: @AhmedFerjani: The question is a bit unclear. Do you have an idea what the structure of the JSON should look like? And do you have a `std::tuple<X,Y,Z>` which should match that structure? Of do you want some kind of tuple which can store _any_ JSON document?

Comment: @MSalters what i cant is a type that can store any type of json, because the args can be :  "args": [1, 2, 3], "args": ["name", "lastname, 22], "args": ["a"] ..

Comment: "any type of json" is too broad for a generic solution. Can you restrict yourself to an array of your parameters, in order of arguments to the function?

Comment: @AhmedFerjani: That would be tricky, as JSON can be nested to any depth. This means `std::variant` is out, since a variant cannot hold itself, but a JSON tree can hold a JSON subtree (or multiple subtrees).

Comment: @Caleth  I'm  trying to call the function with args as parametre, the args does not have a standard structure, for example it can be  : "args": [1, 2, 3], "args": ["name", "lastname, 22], "args": ["a"] ..

Comment: That's still an array of values, which get mapped to `f(1, 2, 3); g("name", "lastname", 22); h("a");`. What you can't have is both that and e.g. `args: { "a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 2 }`

Comment: yes I mean an array of values, @Caleth, I tried the code that you have provided but it didn't work. I'm calling the function like that:         call(f, element["args"]);

Comment: @AhmedFerjani see edit or http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8debbc24f4719117

Comment: @Caleth, thanks but it gives me : error: ‘R’ does not name a type

Comment: Can you replicate that based on the coliru link I gave? I don't know what's different in what you've tried

Comment: @Caleth, I used your code without the templates for the function objects and it really worked, thank you so much, I've been stuck with this issue for about 3 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you only pass non-overloaded functions, function pointers, or function objects with one `operator()`. Lets also assume that the `json` object is always an array of parameters.

First we need to make a tuple from the json and the target arguments

```
template<typename... Args, std::size_t... Is>
std::tuple<Args...> from_json(const json & args, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return { args[Is].get<Args>()... };
}
```

Then we can defined some overloads for different cases. The function (pointer) case is easy.

```
template<typename R, typename... Args>
R call(R(*func)(Args...), const json & args)
{
    return std::apply(func, from_json<Args...>(args, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{}));
}
```

Function objects are harder, we have to look at their `operator()`.

```
template<typename F, typename R, typename... Args>
R call_impl(F && f, const json & args, R(F::*)(Args...))
{
    return std::apply(std::forward<F>(f), from_json<Args...>(args, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{}));
}

template<typename F>
R call(F && f, const json & args)
{
    return call_impl(std::forward<F>(f), args, &F::operator());
}
```